# New to Git Version Control

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, gitversion

I am new to git and i have ran into an issue. I created a feature branch from the master branch and did some commits, even pushed them.

After I realized I was supposed to create my feature branch from another branch which is created from the master. Any suggestions, if there is any workaround here or do I just need to create the new branch as I was supposed to and write all the code again.

Thanks.

Comment: The keyword to search for here is "rebase", which means "recreate commits on top of a different history".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with `git rebase`.

Standing in the branch where you made the changes, after creating the other branch where you should have made the commits

```
git rebase --interactive newbranch
```

Select the commits to pick and push.

Another, equivalent way to do it is manually reverting the commits, stashing the changes and applying them to the other branch.

Stash the changes, in your feature branch where you added the commits

```
git reset --soft HEAD~{NUMBER OF COMMITS}
git stash
```

Check out the other branch and pull the latest changes

```
git checkout otherbanch
git pull origin otherbanch
```

Create a new feature branch to apply the changes to

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Apply the stashed changes

```
git stash apply
```

Fix conflicts if necessary, commit and push.